# the locale id '0' of the source column 'PAT_NUM_ADT' and the locale id '1033' of the destination column 'PAT_ID_OLD' do not match

Tags: sql-server, locale

I get this error when I do a **bulk insert** with `select * from [table_name]`, and another table name:

```
the locale id '0' of the source column 'PAT_NUM_ADT' and the locale id '1033' 
of the destination column 'PAT_ID_OLD' do not match
```

I tried resetting my db collation but this did not help.

Has anyone seen this error?

Answer (score 8):

If you are copying less than a full set of fields from one table to another, whether that table is on another domain across the world, or is collocated in the same database, you just have to select them in order.  SqlBulkCopyColumnMappings do not work.  Yes, I tried.  I used all four possible constructors, and I used them both as SqlBulkCopyMapping objects and just by providing the same information to the Add method of SqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add.

My columns are named the same.  If you're using a different name as well as a different order, you may well find that you have to actually rename the columns.  Good luck.

Comment: It appears that SqlBulkCopy is accepting an IDataReader, but checking to see if it is a SqlDataReader and treating it specially. If you create a wrapper/decorator class that just forwards IDataReader interface calls to the underlying SqlDataReader, everything works correctly.

Comment: This was exactly the source of the problem for me - I added a column in the middle of the destination table that wasn't in the source table and the Bulk Copy was assuming that both source and destination were exactly identical rather than trying to map by name the source columns to the destination columns. Thanks for this explanation!

Comment: @laindir Thanks! Your solution worked. All other solutions suggested filling datatable which obviously slows down performance

Answer (score 7):

I just had this error message when bulk copying some data.  While it might not have been the exact same problem you were having, I was getting the same error.

Specifically, I was doing the following:
SELECT NULL AS ColumnName ...

And the destination was a nullable varchar(3).

In this case, all I needed to do was update my select statement as follows:
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(3),NULL) AS ColumnName...

This worked perfectly and the error message went away!

Answer (score 6):

It is right that when we use SqlBulkCopy, some time it gives error, the best way to map the columns when you are using SqlBulkCopy.

My Previous Code :

```
SqlConnectionStringBuilder cb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder("Data Source=ServerName;User Id=userid;Password=****;Initial Catalog=Deepak; Pooling=true; Max pool size=200; Min pool size=0");

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cb.ConnectionString);

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Name,Class,Section,RollNo from Student", con);

        con.Open();

        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        SqlBulkCopy sbc = new SqlBulkCopy("Data Source=DestinationServer;User Id=destinationserveruserid;Password=******;Initial Catalog=DeepakTransfer; Pooling=true; Max pool size=200; Min pool size=0");

        sbc.DestinationTableName = "StudentTrans";


        sbc.WriteToServer(rdr);


        sbc.Close();
        rdr.Close();
        con.Close();
```

The Code Was giving me the Error as :
The locale id '0' of the source column 'RollNo' and the locale id '1033' of the destination column 'Section' do not match.

Now After Column Mapping my Code Is Running Successfully.

My Modified Code is :

```
SqlConnectionStringBuilder cb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder("Data Source=ServerName;User Id=userid;Password=****;Initial Catalog=Deepak;");

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cb.ConnectionString);

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Name,Class,Section,RollNo from Student", con);

        con.Open();

        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();


        SqlBulkCopy sbc = new SqlBulkCopy("Data Source=DestinationServer;User Id=destinationserveruserid;Password=******;Initial Catalog=DeepakTransfer;");

        sbc.DestinationTableName = "StudentTrans";

        sbc.ColumnMappings.Add("Name", "Name");
        sbc.ColumnMappings.Add("Class", "Class");
        sbc.ColumnMappings.Add("Section", "Section");
        sbc.ColumnMappings.Add("RollNo", "RollNo");

        sbc.WriteToServer(rdr);
        sbc.Close();
        rdr.Close();
        con.Close();
```

This code is running Successfully.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting same error and it turned out I was copying from VARCHAR column in the DataTable to INT.

After I changed the data type it worked flawlessly. I successfully copied subset of fields, specifying proper field mappings (mappings worked by both field name or sequence number).

So make sure your data types are correct.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by sal

> If you are copying less than a full
>   set of fields from one table to
>   another, whether that table is on
>   another domain across the world, or is
>   collocated in the same database, you
>   just have to select them in order.
>   SqlBulkCopyColumnMappings do not work.

is according to my work absolutely right! Thanks for posting it. Everything has to be the same - data types, etc. Each time it finds a mismatch it throws the mysterious Locale Id error - funny yet frustrating as h###.

Answer (score 0):

I would check what your default locale settings are.   Also, you'll need to check the locale of both tables using sp_help to verify they are the same.   If they aren't you'll need to convert it to the correct locale

Answer (score 0):

When you change the Collation of a database the table columns keep the old collation so you need to drop the tables and create them again.

Answer (score 0):

A great way to debug this is to take the sql query being used in your SqlBulkCopy and run it in management studio as a select-into, for instance, change `select * from [table_name]` to `select * into newTable from [table_name]`, then look at the nullability and data types of 'newTable' versus 'table_name'. If there are any differences then you are likely to end up with this misleading error. Adjust the query or target table until they match, and then your command will work.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to Deepak Dwivedi for help. Here is little more hack with **COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT** which finally solved problem for me:

```
SqlConnectionStringBuilder cb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder("Data Source=ServerName;User Id=userid;Password=****;Initial Catalog=Deepak;");
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cb.ConnectionString);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Name COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT Name ,Class COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT Class ,Section COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT Section ,RollNo COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT RollNo  from Student", con);
con.Open();
SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
SqlBulkCopy sbc = new SqlBulkCopy("Data Source=DestinationServer;User Id=destinationserveruserid;Password=******;Initial Catalog=DeepakTransfer;");

sbc.DestinationTableName = "StudentTrans";

sbc.ColumnMappings.Add("Name", "Name");
sbc.ColumnMappings.Add("Class", "Class");
sbc.ColumnMappings.Add("Section", "Section");
sbc.ColumnMappings.Add("RollNo", "RollNo");

sbc.WriteToServer(rdr);
sbc.Close();
rdr.Close();
con.Close();
```